# Gerrit Checklist plugin

Tags: gerrit

Now, I'm finding a Gerrit plugin which support to display a checklist when I do review in web application.

I have researched and found 1 sample source https://github.com/mziwisky/gerrit-checklist. But this sample is working in client (User web page). It means User need to install this script in client side. I think it isn't convenience if I have large number of user. So, I want to move it into Gerrit server side to reduce time of installing in client side.

Have anyone do it ? Please give me information

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the JavaScript file to the gerrit server plugin folder,
you also need to update it as follow:

```
Gerrit.install(function (self) {
// ... plugin JavaScript code here ...
});
```

Comment: One of the developer indicated that it doesn't work in new polymer ui.. Are there any other ways to add a checklist?

Comment: It's also possible using labels as checklist points! similar to code-review label.